# IIS reverse proxy to virtual private ip

Tags: iis, docker, reverse-proxy, boot2docker

I am trying to use IIS 7.5 to Reverse Proxy incoming requests on a specific port to a docker container bound to a port on the private ip of a VirtualBox vm so that my application can be accessible to external hosts on my LAN.

Please assume the following:

- I am running docker with the b2d image inside Windows 7
- `docker machine` receives a virtual private ip such as `192.168.99.100` which is only resolvable to the host machine.
- I have a container built on the `rabbitmq:3-management` image and the management portal is bound to port 32771 on the default gateway of my virtual machine
- I want requests across the network to `http://mymachine:32771` to reverse proxy through IIS 7.5 for port 32771 from my virtual machine and show the RabbitMQ management portal that displays privately for me if I navigate to `http:192.168.99.100:32771`

Can anyone show me examples of the inbound and outbound rewrite rules that I would need to accomplish this?

This is what I have tried so far based on the sparse samples I've found on IIS reverse proxying, and I placed this inside a web.config at my `inetpub/wwwroot` but the rules are not applying (even after an `iisreset`)

> Note that in my config below, I was looking to RP any requests containing "rabbit/" -rather than a specific port- but it is not proxying either.
>
> Edit: [Note] I have also tried `http://rabbit.(my-machine-name?)(/+?.*)?$|(.*)/rabbit(/+?.*)?$` to capture anything coming to my machine on either the `rabbit.` sub or the `/rabbit` path. I validated the capture rule but the RP still does not proxy.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RP requests for Rabbit to virtual private IP" stopProcessing="false">
            <match url="(.*)rabbit/(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://192.168.99.100:32771/{R:1}" />
            <serverVariables>
                <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
            </serverVariables>
        </rule>
    </rules>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="RP requests from Rabbit to outbound" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml">
            <match  filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script"
                pattern="^http(s)?://192.168.99.100:32771/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="/rabbit/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
            <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml">
                <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
            </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
    </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

In the past, I would just stand up Apache and bring in `mod_proxy` for its simplicity and documentation, but I would prefer to know how to implement this in IIS.

Comment: Use URL Rewrite in IIS http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but that guide has already been followed and its guidance is insufficient; followed it to the T and I get nothing but 404.2s and no FRT log.

Comment: <rule name="ARR_server_proxy" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="*" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="http//:192.168.99.100:32771/{R:0}" />
</rule>
Then navigate to "http://mymachine"

Comment: @RicardoC ...that would reverse proxy the entire host, which is not the goal.  ...or are you proposing that as a test to see if the behavior changes?

Comment: It all seems counter intuitive, I know, I struggled with it too. Give it a try. (unless I totally misunderstood your intent of course). "Match" is the request your machine (the proxy) receive, and "rewrite" is the actual web application (the source) doing the work.

Comment: @RicardoC I think you are misunderstanding my intent. Lets say that I have 3 applications exposed externally on the host IP and I want 2 of them to reverse proxy to 2 different internal sockets and 1 to not reverse proxy at all. Your rule would RP them all to the same private socket, which would work for the correctly mapped application and would break the other 2. Do you have a suggestion that would accomplish what I just mentioned?

Comment: @kalanbates well yes, you need to select three ports, one for each app, and two rewrite rules, thats what the match url is for, use it to match the two apps to reverse. And I didn't misunderstood then. That is exactly what I was thinking, except that only thinking on one app.

Comment: @RicardoC then thank you very much for your suggestion, but the "simple" approach had already been tried.  If you are vouching that it should in fact work for my scenario then I will look elsewhere in my configuration for the problem.

Comment: @K.AlanBates did you find the correct way to setup IIS proxy for rabbitmq ?